# Suppress 'ae' and 'oe' ligatures in baskervaldx

Tags: luatex, fontspec, microtype, ligatures, selnolig

I'm using `Baskervaldx` font with `fontspec` and LuaLaTeX, but I can't suppress 'ae' and 'oe' ligatures using either

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={NoCommon,NoContextual,NoHistoric,NoDiscretionary}}
```

or `microtype` and `\DisableLigatures[a]{encoding = *, family = * }`

(Actually, I don't know if this is the right way.)

`\usepackage{Baskervaldx}` works, as does `\usepackage{selnolig} \nolig{ae}{a|e} \nolig{oe}{o|e}`.

Is there a way of suppressing these ligatures using either `fontspec` or `microtype`?

MWEs that don't work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={NoCommon,NoContextual, NoHistoric,NoDiscretionary},
    Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}}
\setmainfont{baskervaldx}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}

\begin{document}  
Michael doesn’t finalize.    
\end{document}
```

This one doesn't work either:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{baskervaldx}

\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[a]{encoding = *, family = * }

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}

\begin{document}
Michael doesn’t finalize.   
\end{document}
```

The next two MWEs do work:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{baskervaldx}

\usepackage{selnolig}
\nolig{ae}{a|e}
\nolig{oe}{o|e}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}

\begin{document} 
Michael doesn’t finalize.  
\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Baskervaldx}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}

\begin{document}  
Michael doesn’t finalize.   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it a problem with the font? Does it have a feature which lets you access 'regular' ligatures without triggering things like `ae` becoming 'æ'?

Comment: In general, you can locally suppress any ligature by interposing curly braces: a{}e.

Comment: Why do you want to suppress ligatures?

Comment: @Bernard The problem is that this font, by default, produces “Michæl” and other odditities.

Comment: Even not typing `æ` in the source-code?

Comment: @Bernard Right.  Putting œ and æ in the `rlig` feature is goofy, but that’s what the designer did.

Comment: for `microtype` to be able to disable the ligatures you'd have to load the font with the option `Renderer=Basic`.

Comment: @Mico Just used texworks again on the MWE, and you're right, the fi ligature of finalize works. Don't know what had happened when I tried last night.

Comment: @Mico - OK, question edited.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As expected, Baskervaldx defines its f-ligatures in the `liga` feature, and its ‘ct,’ ‘sp,’ and ‘st’ ligatures in `dlig`; bizarrely, it puts ‘ae’ and ‘oe’ ligatures, both upper- and lowercase, in `rlig`, i.e., Required Ligatures, which are on by default.  This is almost always a problem, even in languages where these ligatures are sometimes mandatory.

The solution, apart from finding a better Baskerville, is to turn off required ligatures. This will leave your f-ligatures in place, and when you need ‘æ’ or ‘œ,’ you can still get it by typing it (by whatever methods your text editor or operating system allows) or by using `\ae`, `\oe`, etc.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,polyglossia}
\setmainfont{baskervaldx}[
  Ligatures=NoRequired,
  Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\begin{document}
Michael hasn’t finalized his translation of the \textit{De cælo.}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. A followup question for you: why does use of the Baskervaldx package work?

Comment: Reading `.sty` files isn’t my forte, but it looks as if `Baskervaldx.sty` is designed to support `pdftex` rather than `xetex` or `luatex`. So it provides ways for `pdftex` to get f-ligatures, real superiors, lowercase figures, and other desirable glyphs, but doesn’t try to create an implementation of the counterproductive `rlig`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180429/ is relevant to the font package vs. fontspec issue.