# Why does Baskervald ADF turn "ae" into "æ" with fontenc?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

No idea what's going on here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
Path = {/FONTDIR/},
Extension = .otf
]
{BaskervaldADFStd}

\begin{document}

Ae ae

\end{document}
```

... Anyone?

Comment: Does the posting [Suppress 'ae' and 'oe' ligatures in baskervaldx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/404965/5001) help? (I can't run your example because I don't have font `BaskervaldADFStd` on my system). At any rate, adding the option `Ligatures=NoRequired` to the `\setmainfont` should get rid of the "required" `ae` and `oe` ligatures.

Comment: No, that does not fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `BaskervaldADFStd`, the `ae` and `oe` ligatures are classified as "required" ligatures. `fontspec` enables required ligatures by default. To change this setting, add the option `Ligatures=NoRequired` to the `\setmainfont` instruction.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{BaskervaldADFStd}[Ligatures={NoRequired}]
\begin{document}  
ae oe AE OE 

\ae\ \oe\ \AE\ \OE

\em
ae oe AE OE 

\ae\ \oe\ \AE\ \OE
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aside: In this font, the italic ae and oe ligatures are barely distinguishable. Not great, I'd say.