# How can I fix this polyglossia/fontscpec conflict?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, polyglossia

Here's my MWE, it appears replacing `MedeivalSharp`with any TTF file will do the trick.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[osf,proportional]{Baskervaldx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\newfontfamily\msharp[
Path = {/home/kristian/.fonts/},
Extension = .ttf
]
{MedievalSharp}
\begin{document}

{\msharp{This is Medieval Sharp.}}

But this is not Baskerville.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use the Baskervaldx package with xetex, its encoding is not suitable for this engine.

Comment: XeTeX does not use T1, don't load `fontenc`. Also, as @UlrikeFischer mentioned, don't load `Baskervaldx`. Use `\setmainfont` from `fontspec`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, you are right. Now I must find something as good as Baskervaldx. 

Oleg Lobachev -- Duly noted, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I figured out a solution thanks to the comments above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={NoRequired}}

\setmainfont[
Ligatures = TeX,
Path = /home/kristian/.fonts/,
BoldFont = Baskervaldx-Bol.otf,
ItalicFont = Baskervaldx-Ita.otf,
BoldItalicFont  = Baskervaldx-BolIta.otf]
{Baskervaldx-Reg.otf}

\newfontfamily\msharp[
Path = {/home/kristian/.fonts/},
Extension = .ttf
]
{MedievalSharp}

\begin{document}
{\msharp{This is Medieval Sharp.}}

And this is \textsc{Baskerville}. 12345. \textit{test} -- \textbf{test}
\end{document}
```

I added `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={NoRequired}}` to get rid of the strange (OE, AE) ligatures.

Comment: Do you mean in words like Cæsar, œuvre, Phœbe, æther,  ælf, Bignoniaceæ? It is strange seeing them typeset without the ligatures, unless there are technical limitations like typewriters. They do activate the spell-checkers, though, and usage is beginning to fade.

Comment: @Cicada See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404970/ But this fix is no longer needed: someone seems to have removed the `rlig` feature from the version of the fonts in TeX Live.

Comment: You may be interested in [Baskervville](https://github.com/anrt-type/ANRT-Baskervville) and [Open Baskerville](http://klepas.org/openbaskerville/).