# Simulate handwriting with LaTeX

Tags: fonts

I am looking for a way to randomize characters rendering, to simulate handwriting.

I already saw [this](http://code.google.com/p/handlatex/), but it's not enough for me, only the position of the words are randomized.

Comment: Can you use opentype fonts with `xetex` or `luatex`, or do you need a solution for `pdftex`?

Comment: Lualatex is preferable to both

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29425/7883

Comment: Of course, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-do-i-make-my-document-look-like-it-was-written-by-a-cthulhu-worshipping-madm is related to this.  It is only the third highest voted question on this site.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes To be fair, the OP may not be looking for the handwriting of a Cthulhu-worshipping madman... ;).

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old topic. Since I could not find anything, I started a small python script that do what I wanted to do.

For those who would like to take part, or just have a look, it's here:
https://github.com/arodier/manuscript

Comment: I don't see how this is related to LaTeX?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the final result is what I want to achieve, with or without LaTeX.