# Special fonts in math expressions (for CNC machines)

Tags: fonts, xetex, font-metrics

There are many questions about fonts in TeX, but we have a special need so I'm asking a new question. We are designing a CNC machine that will execute mathematical expressions. Therefore, we need to use a font that can be translated into strokes, such as one of the Hershey fonts. Is that possible to do (with XeTex)? If so, will the results be good, or are there issues with metrics?

Comment: most commonly available fonts are outline rather than stroked these days, you could use them as type3 fonts in pdflatex I think, if you have the fonts. (link?)

Comment: More information would be helpful.  Can you provide a link to a font you have in mind?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224731/alternative-to-metafont

Comment: There would be a lot of work involved in supporting stroke fonts in XeTeX --- and I don't see the appeal --- monoline and boring. Why not instead use a V-bit and V-carve/engrave the text? It looks much nicer.