# How do I make my document look like it was handwritten?

Tags: fonts, typography

I have an exam coming up next Monday. We are allowed to bring a sheet of paper with information of our choosing written on it. To my disappointment, it is required to be *hand*written. Over the years, I have developed a distinct distaste for my own handwriting.

So before mustering the necessary resolve to create something ugly with pen and paper, I decided to first check out what options there are to make a `LaTeX` document look as handwritten as possible. And by the way, I really mean handwritten by an ordinary respectable human being, not some [Cthulhu-worshipping gibbering madman, unhinged by the horrors he has witnessed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-do-i-make-my-document-look-like-it-was-written-by-a-cthulhu-worshipping-madm).

Bonus requirement (perhaps this also helps to distinguish this question from others): If possible, I'd like this to work with online `LaTeX` distributions such as [`ShareLaTeX`](https://www.sharelatex.com/).

Comment: Well, if I were the teacher and found out you have *printed* notes, I'd consider it cheating even if the notes are in a font that emulates handwriting. `;-)`

Comment: Your instructor might not allow this solution, should he discover what you have done. Consider asking him for an exception to his rule. Perhaps he will be pleased that you know LaTeX.

Comment: @EthanBolker I did. Unfortunately, he said no. Something about it being an unfair advantage if he made exceptions to that rule after the fact. Not sure why it would be unfair. He could lift the rule altogether. It's not like anyone starts writing those sheets anytime sooner than the night before the exam... Also, I don't think knowing  `LaTeX` is that big a deal anymore.

Comment: @egreg I'd consider it cheating too. The rule was clearly stated after all. However, I don't think I'll really take what I typed into the exam (depends on the end result, I guess). It's more like a fun project now to keep me from actual studying.

Comment: Since you asked (as was right) and he said "no" you'd better do it only for fun.

Comment: @Casimir In that case I endorse the project, that looks very much like procrastination!

Comment: Hermann Zapf designed the `euler` math font to emulate the handwriting of a (very neat) mathematics professor at the chalkboard.

Comment: TeXLive also provides several `uncial` fonts, and among these Carolingan Miniscules really does look like handwriting of a medieval monk.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29425/7883

Answer (score 5):

Use `xelatex` of course, along with a cursive font (there's plenty free online).

**Warning:** This might not be sufficient, it still looks too "clean" and the lines too straight for it to be actually handwritten.<sup>1</sup>

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont{Cursive standard}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

---

<sup>**1:** That is unless you draw lines with a pencil, write, and then delete the lines.</sup>

Comment: I know I said it's a bonus requirement but isn't there anything that will work with [`ShareLaTeX`](https://www.sharelatex.com)?

Comment: @Casimir It should work with it, try using this guide: [Using your favourite fonts with ShareLaTeX](https://it.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/04/02/using-your-favourite-fonts-with-sharelatex.html). Although it'd be a lot easier if you just downloaded the font and compiled locally. :D

Comment: That's great. Didn't know about that.