# Looking for fonts to show handwriting forgery in fiction

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I write novels using Latex (luatex).  I would like to show a hand written letter written by one of the characters. There is a short sentence at the end of the letter, which has been added by another character trying to forge the original writer's handwriting - looks the same at first but then on closer inspection it is not quite right. Has anybody an idea how to add an effect to some text, so that it looks like someone has tried to forge it?

Comment: This question would fit better at https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ok thanks will try that

Comment: You could rephrase your question and ask whether someone has an idea how to add an effect to some text, so that it looks like someone has tried to forge it. Maybe this could better fit here.

Comment: yes that would be better  - thanks

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29425 may be of interest — but there’s still more regularity here than in, um, authentic forgeries.

Comment: Do have a look at the `novel` document class (I wrote it), which is specifically designed for your purpose, if that will be a paper book. Yes, it has been used for fiction books, but only paper print (not Ebooks). As for your question: As others noted, it is really a graphics design question.

Answer (score 5):

You can choose another handwriting font if you do not
have the LUCIDA (https://tug.org/store/lucida/index.html)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lucida-otf}
\begin{document}
\LucidaHandwriting
\makebox[0pt][l]{Some nonsense as short text}%
{\fontspec{LucidaHandwritingOT}[FakeSlant=-0.3]%
Some nonsense as short text\par}

Some nonsense as short text

\fontspec{LucidaHandwritingOT}[FakeSlant=-0.3]%
Some nonsense as short text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's good! - funnily enough I was just reading the fontspec manual and just discovered fakeslant - nice one - thanks.